# Rails newbie having trouble getting commenters name to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a blog in rails as my first project. For some reason I have been having a ton of trouble with the comments portion of it. I'm sure it is something small I am overlooking.

I can get the comments to show on the correct post now, but I cannot get the name of the person to show. If I do comment.user.name I get this error

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

However if I do comment.user it will show something like this: `#<User:0x466cd28>.` I also get an error when trying to do `<%=time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)  %>`

```
undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
```

However I can do comment.created_at without an error.

Here it is on github in case it is easier :https://github.com/Mciocca/blog

Here is the part that displays the comments being rendered on the posts#view

```
 <% if @post.comments.any? %>
 <% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
 <div class="comment-name">
 <%= comment.user %>  <%=comment.created_at%></div> 
 <div class='comment-content'>
<%= comment.comment %>
</div> 
<% end %>
<% else %>
<h3>Be the first to comment!</h3>
<% end %>
```

Here is the comment model and controller (comment is the comments content, bad naming choice)

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :comment, :post_id
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user

validates :comment, presence: true

end


class CommentsController < ApplicationController

      def create
        @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @comment.post
            else
                render '/blog'
            end
    end

def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
end

end
```

Here is the User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :name, :password_confirmation
 has_secure_password

 has_many :comments
 has_and_belongs_to_many :posts

 before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
 before_save :create_remember_token

 validates_confirmation_of :password
 validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
 validates_presence_of :email
 validates_uniqueness_of :email
 validates_presence_of :name

private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end


end
```

Here is the Post model and controller

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :preview, :title
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy, :order => "created_at DESC"



  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
end



class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build

  end

  # GET /posts/new
  # GET /posts/new.json
  def new
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Sorry for the long post! Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Are you certain there are no comments that don't have a user? You can always use `comment.user.try(:name)` to avoid raising an error in that case.

Comment: All comments should have a user. You cannot leave a comment unless you are signed in.

Comment: If comment.user works, and comment.user.name doesn't, and it's consistent, simmering is very odd. So odd I find it difficult to believe.

Comment: I pushed it to github so you can try yourself:https://github.com/Mciocca/blog

Answer (score 0):

`@comment = @post.comments.build` in your Post model's `show` method is creating a new comment in your `comments` collection, but there is no user name for that new comment.

Comment: can you expand on this? I am not trying to get a comment name, I am trying to get a user name.